# Are there infinitely many nonnegative integers not of the following four forms?

Tags: number-theory

The four forms are:

$3x^2 + (6y-4)x - y$

$3x^2 + (6y-2)x + y - 1$

$3x^2 + (6y-3)x + y - 1$

$3x^2 + (6y-3)x - y\ $,$\ x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$

For example: $4=3 \cdot1^2+(6 \cdot1-4) \cdot 1-1\ $ is the minimum number of the four forms, so that $\ 0, \ 1, \ 2,\ 3\ $  must not be of the four forms. How can one prove that the set of these numbers is infinite?

Comment: ...because people at Math Stack Exchange won't see any progress made here, and vice-versa, so they (and we) could end up wasting time repeating what is already known.

Answer (score 6):

Let me denote these forms by $f_i(x,y)$ for $i=1,2,3,4$, respectively. Notice that
$$12\cdot f_1(x,y) = (6x - 1)\cdot (12y + 6x - 7) - 7\\
12\cdot f_2(x,y) = (6x + 1)\cdot (12y + 6x - 5) - 7\\
12\cdot f_3(x,y) = (6x + 1)\cdot (12y + 6x - 7) - 5\\
12\cdot f_4(x,y) = (6x - 1)\cdot (12y + 6x - 5) - 5$$

Now, if $(12k+5, 12k+7)$ is a twin prime pair, then $k$ is not represented by either of these four forms with positive $x,y$.

P.S. Suprisingly, this question is very similar to the one I answered yesterday: at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164792/are-there-infinitely-many-natural-numbers-not-covered-by-one-of-these-7-polynomi/164859#164859

Comment: @Dietrich: Both questions come from stackexchange but they are from two different people. I find it surprising when two people independently ask very similar questions at the same time.

Comment: @Dietrich: You're wrong, both accounts are *unregistered*. Their name and gravatar are the same, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution without assuming (a stronger form of) the twin prime conjecture. [This paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa24/aa2451.pdf) by Iwaniec shows that if $P(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2+ex+fy+g$ satisfies some mild conditions that are easy to check and valid in this case, then the number of primes up to N represented by $P(x,y)$ is $\ll \frac{N}{(\log N)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$, so the quadratic polynomials in the question represent just a zero density set of the primes, and the same argument applies to any such finite collection quadratic polynomials as long as the polynomials satisfy the quite simple requirements of theorem 1 of Iwaniec's paper. The conditions are:

- $\frac{dP}{dx}$ and $\frac{dP}{dy}$ are linearly independent,
- $P(x,y)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$,
- $b^2-4ac$ not a perfect square,
- $gcd(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)=1$,
- $af^2-bef+ce^2+(b^2-4ac)g\neq 0$
- $P(x,y)$ represents arbitrarily large odd integers.

EDIT: I was too hasty; in this case $b^2-4ac=b^2$ is actually a perfect square. Then Iwaniec's paper actually says that the number of primes up to $N$ represented by $P(x,y)$ is $\gg \frac{N}{\log N}$, so this does not work (unless there is some way to estimate the constant).